# Visual Studio Code - Download Extension File

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code installed on a server that has no internet connection and therefore VSC cannot connect to the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode).

Is there a way to download the extension file from the marketplace so I can copy it over to ***%USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions*** and install it manually? I am trying to get the powershell extension.

Answer (score 2):

- Install VSCode on a PC with internet connection
- Install all the extensions you want to use
- Each installed extension is placed in a subdirectory of `%USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions`. Copy those folders and place them in the same directory on the other machine

Comment: I unfortunately do not have admin rights on my work laptop to install it locally. And do not wish to install it on any of our connected servers. But it seems this is the only way. Thanks.